# Replace all occurrences without changing file endings

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

To replace all occurrences of a word with another in all files with a particular extension in the current directory I use this command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zz' -exec sed -i '' "s/replace_this/with_this/" {} +
```

The problem is that it adds `\n` to the end of files that do not end in `\n`. Now don't get me wrong, I love `\n` terminated files as much as the next person. But I don't want all those changes in my git diff. What's a command to run that does the same thing but without touching file endings?

By the way I'm using emacs with counsel-projectile so if there's a handy tool there instead that would be fine.

macOS 10.13.4

Comment: Please include an example of the file before/after running the command.

Comment: @l'L'l Before it has no final newline, after it does. For example `echo -n hello > a.txt && echo hello > b.txt && hexdump -C a.txt && hexdump -C b.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to `perl` **pie** instead of `sed` with something like this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/replace_this/with_this/'
```

In your case:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zz' -exec perl -pi -e  "s/replace_this/with_this/" {} +
```