# How to add a new line in freebsd 10.2

Tags: sed, freebsd

In freebsd 10.2

I have a text file ie. test.txt 
The file contains The follow lines

```
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3
    option
    #i want to add here Mynewline text 
    Line4
    Line5
    Line6
    Line7
```

i try
**sed -i '' 's/option/option\Mynewline/g' test.txt**

```
 Line1
 Line2
 Line3
 optionMynewline
 Line4
 Line5
 Line6
 Line7
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `awk`, this should do:

```
awk '/option/ {$0=$0"\nMy new line"} 1' file
```

If `option` is found, add new line and text to the line, and then print all

Comment: i want to insert the line in the text not print them if i do test.txt >> test.text at the end i take double contains

Comment: @xrealtvxrealtv  With  `awk`, you do:  `awk 'code' file > tmp && mv tmp file` to edit the original file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '.bak' -e '/^option/p' -e '//s/.*/myNewLine/' file
```

Or:

```
sed -i '' '/^option/{p;s/.*/newline/;}' file
```

Or:

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '.bak' -f /dev/stdin file
/option/a\
newline
!
```

Or:

```
sed -i '' '/^option/{G;s/$/myNewLine/;}' file
```

Or:

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin file
/option/p
//c\
newline
!
```

Comment: nothing works of all those.sed: 1: "/^option/{x;s/.*/myNewL ...": extra characters at the end of G command and the first one it prints the contans does not insert the line

Comment: I apologize. freebsd 10.4 has some peculiarities. It seems any of the `a`, `i` or `c` commands need to come from a file (see amendments) or the entire script should be in a file. Also any commands between `{` and `}` needs to end in `;`. Finally, the `-i` option if empty needs a space between it and the two single quotes (see the last example).

Answer (score 0):

BSD sed does not interpret '\n' as new line, so you can use an actual newline, escaped by a backslash.

```
cat f.txt 
Line1
Line2
Line3
option
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7

$ sed  -i '' 's/option/option\
Mynewline/g' f.txt

$ cat f.txt 
Line1
Line2
Line3
option
Mynewline
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
```

Another option is to install and use gsed.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
perl -pi -e 's/option/option\n/' file
```

or

```
perl -pi -e 's/option/option\n# my new line/' file
```

The file will be now something like:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
option
# my new line
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
```

By using "perl pie" besides adding only the new line it won't modify the file like with `sed` that adds a new `\n` if file doesn't end with a `\n` ([Replace all occurrences without changing file endings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50122548/1135424))